# why is this redux toolkit users variable always undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to add a user to state.users in a redux toolkit slice.  Here's userManagementSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  users: [],
}

export const userManagementSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userManagement',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      const user = action.payload;
      state.users.push(user);
    },
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { addUser } = userManagementSlice.actions

export default userManagementSlice.reducer
```

Here's key code from a component that listens to the users in global state and attempts to add a user to that array via dispatch:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState();
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState();
const users = useSelector((state) => state.users)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const addUser2 = () => {
    const user = {
        firstName,
        lastName
    }
    dispatch(addUser(user));
}
```

However, the USERS UPDATED value logged to the console from the component is always undefined:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('USERS UPDATED: ' + users);

    // reset inputs
    setFirstName('');
    setLastName('');

}, [users]);
```

Here's the configureStore setup:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userManagementReducer from '../features/userManagement/userManagementSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userManagement: userManagementReducer,
  },
})
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you register the `userManagementSlice` reducer in your `configureStore` call?

Comment: I updated my original post above to include the configureStore call.  it seems to look correct to me

Comment: this is what a state.users watch looks like for my slice.  is this expected?  i would have expected a simple array

state.users: Proxy
[[Handler]]
: 
Object
[[Target]]
: 
Array(1)
[[IsRevoked]]
: 
false

Comment: @random512 yes that is expected when you are looking at the state inside of the reducer.  redux-toolkit uses Proxies under the hood to handle immutability.  The state that you get from `useSelector` should be a plain array.

Answer (score 1):

You are mounting the slice at `userManagement`, so your selector would have to be

```js
const users = useSelector((state) => state.userManagement.users)
```